# Use a class decorator to alter subclass methods

Tags: typescript

How can I use class decorators to alter the decorated class's subclasses' methods?
This is an example of altering the class's own methods, but it does not work for the subclasses' own methods:

```
export function guardAllNonConstructorOwnMethodsAgainstBadArguments(
  constructor: Function
) {
  const badArguments = new Set(['', undefined, null]);
  const prototype = constructor.prototype;
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(prototype)
    .filter(
      ownPropertyName =>
        typeof prototype[ownPropertyName] === 'function' &&
        ownPropertyName !== 'constructor'
    )
    .forEach(propertyName => {
      const nonConstructorOwnMethod = prototype[propertyName];
      prototype[propertyName] = function(...args: any[]) {
        const everyArgumentIsGood = args.every(arg => !badArguments.has(arg));
        if (everyArgumentIsGood) {
          return nonConstructorOwnMethod.bind(this)(...args);
        }
      };
    });
}
```

I.e., for this example, how can I modify this decorator such that the methods of the subclasses of the class this decorator is applied to are also guarded against "bad arguments"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class decorators get called once, at the time of class definition. They do not act on subclasses. If you want subclasses to be decorated, you should probably decorate each subclass.

Otherwise, as far as I know, there are no global hooks you can set to trigger code to run when a subclass happens to extend an already-decorated superclass.  The closest I could imagine doing is having subclasses call your code *upon the creation of their first instance*. That is, `class Subclass extends Superclass {}` doesn't trigger anything, but `new Subclass()` will trigger the code, and the next `new Subclass()` will not.  It might be good enough for you.  Here's one way I can imagine doing it:

```
const callForThisClassAndForEachSubclass =
    (cb: ((ctor: new (...args: any) => void) => void)) =>
        (ctor: new (...args: any) => any) => {
            const registry = new Set<new (...args: any) => any>();
            const alreadyDecorated = Symbol();
            const {[ctor.name]: newCtor} = {
                [ctor.name]: class extends ctor {
                    constructor(...args: any) {
                        super(...args);
                        const thisCtor = this.constructor as new (...args: any) => any;
                        if (!registry.has(thisCtor)) {
                            cb(thisCtor);
                            registry.add(thisCtor);
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            cb(newCtor);
            registry.add(newCtor);
            return newCtor;
        };
```

This creates a registry of constructors and calls the callback only once for each constructor it sees.  We have to override the superclass's constructor to get this to happen when subclasses are constructed.  It's pretty complicated looking, but let's see it in action:

```
const log = (ctor: new (...args: any) => any) => {
    console.log("I'm decorating this", ctor);
}

console.log("before superclass declaration")  
@callForThisClassAndForEachSubclass(log)
class Superclass {

} // I'm decorating this function Superclass()
new Superclass(); // nothing

console.log("before subclass declaration")
class Subclass extends Superclass {
} // nothing

console.log("before subclass instance")
new Subclass(); // I'm decorating this function Subclass()
console.log("before subclass instance")
new Subclass(); // nothing

console.log("before subclass2 declaration")
class Subclass2 extends Superclass {
} // nothing

console.log("before subclass2 instance")
new Subclass2(); // I'm decorating this function Subclass2()
console.log("before subclass2 instance")
new Subclass2(); // nothing

console.log("before subsubclass declaration")
class SubSubclass extends Subclass {
} // nothing

console.log("before subsubclass instance")
new SubSubclass(); // I'm decorating this function SubSubclass2()
console.log("before subsubclass instance")
new SubSubclass(); // nothing
```

You can see that the function `log()` is called once for `SuperClass` at class creation time, and once for each subclass upon the first instance being created.  If, instead of `log`, you use your `guardAllNonConstructorOwnMethodsAgainstBadArguments` function, it *might* work out for you (especially since that seems only to touch methods) but I can't be sure because the question doesn't include the intended use case.

Anyway, even if it doesn't work, it might help you think of an alternative solution based on overriding the superclass constructor to perform custom actions when subclass constructors are called.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?experimentalDecorators=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBMCGAbRAxEAnAKgCwJYQGFF4IIBBMAEzXQFF5hsBlAVwCNhjSYBeAKBiCYACmBsAXCNFQMksAFMA7iIB0a+OgDmESfDABPAJS8AfDABuIXJWM8zl64dsmBQt9NkwFy4WpUbtXQNnGD0jUxgAb1c3WLhwaBh0eU18KHR9Xi8lGCZ5KAAeb1V1LR1Q4Iiwk2FDAG4YuKFQSFgkZPhKfQAReVB0eCh5SiymfQBbNhBEWoam2JbEyIBtYBl0FTB4cfkAXTklAnWAXyzo+fnV9c3tvclOEggYeQAPIaontYwoxoumxfSLC+6F8pUCFXC5z+0MEEBYAAd5CC-AEIPVfjD-glYFA8IR1llcfgVAD0ECCSRsj4UWUguE7BC5pi-rgAGYiACEyVS0AyKmwJGERPxGCcP2ZzLEQrxR1FTIl0O5aT5nUo0vwsvQ6IV82OGOZeoVhuhx3lFyl3k12sVKWV+n8lDVlvW1r+ySgLHQYCpmrNblNfD4AHoQ6Gw+HQ4GATBECBNFkPOgDtSweUwiF0xEoYJFtN5CpY5phAAiACSAHJxjBKH0MINcGB48LiwAaOAuhp6vi5xD5wsltjyVkYeQwOGI9APbg1h4DKC4cDFwx8AACCGQNBwGq45CoNHojFYHB3wkLy6nT1YE4vPz4pxDMArVZndfnjZgwpgrJYYDWC+9V5IhetR8MUgGTie9QwA+YAgESjZRgkeYFnGA5DiOY7sDeM7EHO-5Lt2O65FhRGvO8lCXgiQFEdE95Bl4cF4Ah3ZIb2KFFsWg7DskmHHo8MANtAejAPIBFgSRjyzNB9FPtWtZ4e+n7fr+87gMRfGkCBPZ9qhnHoTxcIaU8glQMJonLuJRlSTBjENpoiGQMh-Z6dxo6GReABMcmzvWi7nkRR6ec8bzyB8xHXjRd7SQx8H2Sxjlsc5XEYe5O5eSZZliTkgVpdZMmVt5r52R+eJfj+f5qTljweVprE6RxyUGRJpDpa0mUWdlzUQDVUE2bFDkQE5umNW57CpfxOEaL5YAETeR5VdwZGhRR6k3rR0Wwf18WDYlw36aNbDjdwGW-uZoGdWwC0QHlj4FS+ClNqVykVQB7BXT121DQ1+28UdxltadWXKPNXU3ZtTFxXwQA)

Comment: Great and very useful answer, has my upvote. The reason I'm not accepting it is because it does not provide a direct answer (i.e. it provides an alternative), nor does it factually state that the direct answer is impossible

Comment: Class decorators do not act on subclasses, so the answer to the question as stated is "this is not directly possible".  I've rephrased my first several sentences to be more explicit about this.

Comment: Ah you're right. I did write "use class decorators", but what I was actually intending to ask would have to have that rephrased as "use something akin to class decorators". That was my mistake; your answer is correct.